# Django pagination with mysql databse not working properly

Tags: python, mysql, django, pagination, django-pagination

I am trying to connection Django pagination with mysql Database but i am facing some problem

> Problem

1. it's work fine when data is less.
2. but when data is in millions it take 2-3 minutes to load the data in html page, even i am fetching only 100 rows at a time.
3. every time I change the page it take 2-3 minute to load the data in html page

> view.py

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
```

def displayLogs(request):
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.shortcuts import renderimport mysql.connector

```
con = mysql.connector.connect (host="localhost", user = "root", passwd ="12345", db =  "database")

cur=con.cursor()




sql = "SELECT * FROM Table "
cur.execute(sql)
user_list=cur.fetchall()
searchlen=len(user_list)
paginator = Paginator(user_list, 100)
page = request.GET.get('page')
users = paginator.get_page(page)



return render(request,'displayLogs.html',{'users': users,'searchlen':searchlen})
```

> template.html

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th ><center><b>ActivityDate</center></th>
        <th><center><b>Activity</center></th>
        <th><center><b>ActorUserPrinicipalName</center></th>
        <th><center><b>Target1Name</center></th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr class="gradeX">
        {% for item in users %}
         <td>{{item.0}}</td>
         <td>{{item.1}}</td>
         <td>{{item.6}}</td>
         <td class="center">{{item.10}}</td>
        </tr>
        
       {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
      <tr>
       <th ><center><b>ActivityDate</center></th>
        <th><center><b>Activity</center></th>
        <th><center><b>ActorUserPrinicipalName</center></th>
        <th><center><b>Target1Name</center></th>
      </tr>
      </tfoot>
      

<div class="pagination" style="border-style:inset;border-width:5px;padding-bottom: 5px">
 {% if users.has_previous %}

 <a class="pagination-action" href="?page=1"> <i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></a>

 <a class="pagination-action" href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number}}"> <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></a>

 {% endif %}

 {% for num in users.paginator.page_range %}
  {% if users.number == num %}

   <span class="pagination-number pagination-current"><strong>{{ num }}</strong></span>

  {% elif num > users.number|add:'-3' and num < users.number|add:'3' %}

  <a class="pagination-number" href="?page={{ num }}">{{num}}</a>

  {% endif %}

 {% endfor %}

 {% if users.has_next %}

 <a class="pagination-action" href="?page={{ users.next_page_number }}"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
 <a class="pagination-action" href="?page={{ users.paginator.num_pages }}"> <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"> </i></a>

 {% endif %}
    
 </div>
```

Comment: It seems that each time your fetching all rows from your table and then work with it. Is there any particular reason why don't you use Django ORM?

Comment: Your query is fetching all the rows each time, which with millions of rows is going to take a long time. Is there a specific reason why you're using raw sql instead of Django's ORM? Django's ORM makes this easy to overcome. If you need to use raw sql you'll need to figure out how to programatically insert correct LIMIT and OFFSET statements into your SQL query

Comment: Don't know how to use ORM Can you help me with this?

Comment: How did you create tables? Do you have models? 
Read django docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/overview/